# Reset iPhone screen time passcode without access to original AppleID

Tags: iphone, ios, screen-time

I have a screen time passcode on my iPhone. This was set up by someone else on my behalf, and I don't know the passcode. I'd like to reset it. I no longer have contact with the person and am unable to ask them for the passcode.

I think that they signed in using their Apple ID when configuring screen time, so I am not able to use an Apple ID to reset the passcode. (I've tried to reset the screen time passcode using my own Apple ID. It didn't work and incremented the failed passcode counter).

What are my options? (other than a full wipe/reset of the iPhone, which is undesirable for obvious reasons).

The device is signed in with my personal Apple ID, I have full access otherwise. I've contacted Apple Support but they did not have any suggestions.

Comment: A wipe and reset **is** your option.